# css calc() not supported on Android 4.4 / calc() polyfill

Tags: javascript, html, css, android-4.4-kitkat, calc

I'm developing a webview that should be supported also for Android 4.4. I built my HTML and CSS using also calc() that unfortunatly is not supported for some Android 4.4 devices(https://caniuse.com/calc)... I tried to implement the following polyfill but nothing seems changing: https://github.com/closingtag/calc-polyfill

Maybe I implemented the polyfill uncorrectly, but as I see from the README I just need to implement the JS after I include my css stylesheet.

```
<link href="css/style-splash.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script  src="js/fastclick.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calc.js"></script>
```

Comment: So you download the whole project to your project OR you just copy past that link ? Are you using any framwork to develop ?

Comment: I downloaded the file inside the dist directory (calc.js). I'm not using any framework unfortunatly and neither any packet manager